# Skip payment step in checkout magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, payment

How to skip the Payment step in checkout and place the order. After place order i want to give option to payment for the order amount within a limited period of time to confirming order. I want to know how to achieve this in technical way in magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some free or paid extension like partial payment or pay later. Following is one example of such extension (zip money payment for magento 2).

https://github.com/zipMoney/zip.magento2

It supports buy now and pay later in their gateway.

Comment: I want to remove the payment step from checkout after shipping method go to place order.